# Basics of Dart: Access class paramters

Tags: flutter, dart

I have started learning Dart and Flutter and wanted to understand one concept:

Updated code: try in dartpad

```
class Service{
    String ask = '';
    
    void write (String receivedData){
        ask = receivedData;
    }
  }

class WriteNow{
  String hi = 'hi';
  Service art = Service();
  void okay () {
    art.write(hi);
  }
}

void main () {
  WriteNow a = WriteNow();
  a.okay();
  Service b = Service();
  print(b.ask);
}
```

I run WriteToService first and then ReadFromService, I cannot get the 'Hello', but get the original string ''. Please clarify. Also, how does this scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating different instances of the `Service` class, that's the reason you can't get the updated String. Let me explain, in this piece of code:

```dart
WriteNow a = WriteNow();
a.okay();
```

You are creating an instance of the `Service` class, called `art`. The `art` instance has its member called `ask`, which is empty. When you call `a.okay()`, you are modifying the `ask` member of the `art` instance. So now, if you run this `print(a.art.ask)` you will get the `'hi'` response.

Instead of that, you are creating another instance of the `Service` class, called `b`, and then you are printing the `b.ask` value. Can you see the error? You modified the `art` instance, not the `b` instance.

The `ask` value is not "global" to all the instances of the `Service` class, each instance has its own `ask` value, and each instance can change it without modifying the other instances.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Changed it accordingly. Anyways, now I'm using provider for scoped access to classes, which works better

Answer (score 0):

```
class Service {
    String ask = '';
    
    void write (String receivedData){
        ask = receivedData;
    }
}
```

```
class WriteToService{
    Service a = Service();
    a.write('hello');
}
```

```
class ReadFromService {
    Service b = Service();
    print(b.ask);
}
```

What you are Doing:

**Step 1:** The Service class contains `String ask = '';`

**Step 2:** Running `WriteToService` class

**Step 3:** Running `ReadFromService` class

So `ReadFromService` class displays original String content which is `ask = ''` as it has been reassigned to `String ask = ''`. Scope of the previous entry `hi` of `WriteToService` class was ended.

Correct way to do it:

```
void main() {
  WriteToService ok1 = new WriteToService();
  ReadFromService ok2 = new ReadFromService();
}

String globelVariable = 'hi';

class Service {
  String ask = globelVariable;
  void write(String receivedData) {
    globelVariable = receivedData;
  }
}

class WriteToService {
  Service a = new Service();
  WriteToService() {
    String name = "hello";
    a.write(name);
  }
}

class ReadFromService {
  Service b = new Service();
  ReadFromService() {
    print(b.ask1);
  }
}
```

Now declare a global variable `String globelVariable = 'hi';` and assign it to `String ask = globelVariable;` in class `Service`. In `write` method assign the receiving data to global variable `globelVariable = receivedData;`. Since the scope of global variable doesn't end till the program is terminated it won't loose the value of the string `hello` which is eventually printed when `ReadFromService` class is called.

Test the above code at https://dartpad.dev/

Comment: I did this only... Seems to be some other problem. Probably related to inheritance.

Comment: @In-Vader, I have updated the answer. I am not good at explaining but did my best. If you like the answer, Please vote and select my answer. Feel free to approach me if have any doubts.